How to get set-cookies in react from django
I am running frontend as react and backend as Django.
I've configured CORS and set up my environment for my web application. Within this application, I'm storing some values in session for each user. The requirement is to persist data across subsequent requests from the frontend. However, I'm facing an issue in retrieving the session ID from the response.I've ensured that the CORS policies are correctly configured. Despite this, I'm unable to extract the session ID from the response.I was able to see the sessionid from the Browser but not on react.
Question: How can I properly extract the session ID from the response in my React application?
Could someone guide me on how to properly retrieve the session ID from the response in my setup? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
My CORS
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers,default_methods

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    *default_headers,
)

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    *default_methods,
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # Set to False for security reasons
# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
#     "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
#     "http://localhost:3000",
#     # Add other origins as needed
#     "http://192.168.1.36:3000",
# ]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

My MIDDLEWARE
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  # Include only once
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

my react fetch
const { REACT_APP_SERVER_URL } = 'http://192.168.1.19';

const sendChatMessage = async (message) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.1.19:8000/chat/post`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to send message');
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(response.headers.getSetCookie()); // here the total header is empty, but i am able to see in browser

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error sending message:', error);
  }
};

export default {
  sendChatMessage,
};

I was able to see the session id from the browser, but i am not able to get that in react app. which it look like
Response headers from the Django
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 16 May 2024 10:50:58 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.10.12
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept, Cookie, origin
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 100
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Set-Cookie:  sessionid=hvzruncvvtqhvjice7zfw5rbpnzrxkh2; expires=Thu, 30 May 2024 10:50:58 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure

Request headers from the react
POST /chat/post HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.1.19:8000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36


Additional Details:
I've observed the session ID in the browser's response headers but haven't been successful in accessing it within my React app. The provided response headers include the session ID, but I'm unsure how to retrieve it on the frontend.
Closing:
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
